# Wacom CTH-301/K Cannot disable touch

Tags: 16.04, usb, wacom, graphics-tablet

I'm currently trying to disable the touch input for my Wacom Bamboo CTH-301/K (USB) tablet, but as far as I see, everyone tells me to use either xinput or xsetwacom.

After a lot of tests I've come to the conclusion that the pen and eraser are recognized and work, but the tablet isn't.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:648d Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 056a:0318 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1d57:0006 Xenta Wireless Receiver (RC Laser Pointer)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID-complianp Mouse HID-compliant Mouse   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Pen stylus           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Pen eraser           id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Finger               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID-complianp Mouse HID-compliant Mouse   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see, lsusb shows it as "Wacom Co., Ltd" which is not a good sign as far as I understand other posts around askubuntu, but xinput shows the pen, the eraser and the finger options.

While that seems ok, what intrigues me is that xsetwacom isn't listing the finger device

xsetwacom:

```
Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Pen stylus     id: 14  type: STYLUS    
Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Pen eraser     id: 19  type: ERASER
```

And when I tried to get all the options for the device 13 (Finger) I received this:

xsetwacom --get 13 all

```
Property 'Wacom Tablet Area' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Button Actions' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Button Actions' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Button Actions' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Debug Levels' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Debug Levels' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Sample and Suppress' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Sample and Suppress' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Pressurecurve' does not exist on device.
Option "Mode" "Relative"
Property 'Wacom Hover Click' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Enable Touch' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Hardware Touch Switch' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Enable Touch Gesture' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Proximity Threshold' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Rotation' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Pressure Threshold' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Tool Type' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Serial IDs' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Serial IDs' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Serial IDs' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Serial ID binding' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Serial IDs' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Pressure Recalibration' does not exist on device.
```

Any clues on how I should proceed on getting either the finger part recognized by xsetwacom or to just disable the touch part?

Ps: If I disable device 13 on xinput it disables the pen touch too.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Disabling the device by name `xinput disable Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Finger` might solve the issue of pen touch also being disabled.